# Does thread pool size keep growing for scheduledthreadpoolexecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading

Imagine a situation where tasks are being added to scheduledthreadpoolexecutor. Each of these tasks will keep on running at different periodic intervals.

Although all such tasks will not be running at the same time because each is set at different intervals, there may be a situation where a high number of threads are competing for execution.

Is there any restriction on total number of threads ? It seems there is a restriction on the total number of **idle** threads. And does this concept of idle thread imply that long running tasks (thread) may be destroyed and recreated when needed ?

Answer (score 2):

*Does thread pool size keep growing for scheduledthreadpoolexecutor?*

No. From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html:

```
.... it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads ...
```

*Is there any restriction on total number of threads ?*

Yes. See above.

*It seems there is a restriction on the total number of idle threads.*

I'm not sure what made you think that; nothing in the documentation (or behavior if you test it) implies that.

*And does this concept of idle thread imply that long running tasks (thread) may be destroyed and recreated when needed ?*

Task != thread; this question does not make much sense. A task will occupy its thread for the entire time it is running; therefore a long running task will keep a thread occupied for a long time, reducing the number of threads available for other scheduled tasks during that time. A task will never be destroyed and recreated by the executor, period. The executor may attempt to stop a task, but only if you tell it to do so explicitly, e.g. via `shutdownNow()` which `interrupt()`s all running tasks. Unrelated, a thread in a fixed-size pool will not be destroyed or recreated because it is a fixed-size pool.

Comment: if (long running tasks T = those that run at periodic intervals) what happens if T is large compared to 'corePoolSize' ?

Comment: Then the tasks that can't run yet are stuck in the queue until a thread is available for them to run on. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, as per docs, only guarantees that tasks won't run *before* they are scheduled. It makes no guarantees that they won't be late, which will happen if all threads are busy. Try it.